# Using test functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let F(x) be the fundamental solution for the ODE y''-y=g, i.e. formally F satisfies $F''-F=\delta$. Using test functions, explain that this means $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} F(\varphi'' - \varphi)= \varphi(0)$

So I have been trying to work this problem out and I am not sure where to begin. I came across this problem under a green's second identity but I don't see how that applies here. Any help to get me started would be greatly appreciated.